# Discord.js | How to get user's input and make a message for it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I'm trying to make a Discord bot with javascript, but I'm trying to make it so it can get the user's input and it has to be a person or like a mention, and make it as a message.

So like if I type `!say @Dobie` the bot will say `@Dobie is a son of a cookie` like that, please help me it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty simple to achieve. You have to check if there are any mentions within the message ([`Message.mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions)), and if that's the case, you can just send a reply back to the channel.

Here's an example:

---

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 // Making sure that the author of the message is not a bot.
 if (message.author.bot) return false;

 // Checking if the message's content starts with "!say"
 if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!say')) {
  // Making sure that there is at least one GuildMember mention within the message.
  if (!message.mentions.members.size) return false;

  // Sending the message.
  message.channel.send(
   `${message.mentions.members.first()} is a son of a cookie`
  );
 }
});
```

Comment: It actually worked out pretty well, but if i do "/say batejibj aebjrotbiajert ajeoitbjaeotjb @person" it still worked out so is there any way to fix it? I mean.. it's ok if you don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You'll have to split the message's content into an array using RegEx, which will include the command name and the arguments of the command. Then, you can check if the command equals `!say`. Mine was just an example.